# jTextFields requesting focus (if empty after lostFocus) not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, focus

I have 2 jTextFields and both have listeners for a lostFocus event, if the first textfield lost focus and is empty I want it to regain focus,and almost the same for the second field.
I tried this:

```
String str = MyTextField.getText();
if (str.isEmpty()) 
    MyTextField.requestFocusInWindow();
else ...
```

and it worked at first , but now even if the first textfield is empty the second gains focus and after this everything hangs, I think maybe there are some concurrency issues... Please explain the reason and help me with a solution

Comment: Use **[InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)**

From the javadocs,

> A component's input verifier is consulted whenever the component is **about to lose the focus**. If the component's value is **not acceptable**, the input verifier can take appropriate action, such as **refusing to yield the focus** on the component or replacing the user's input with the last valid value and then allowing the focus to transfer to the next component. However, InputVerifier is **not** called when the focus is **transferred to another toplevel component**.

Here is a sample code based on yours that prevents tabbing to the other text field if the textfield is empty

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FoucsDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new FoucsDemo();
            }
        });

    }

    FoucsDemo()
    {
        JFrame jFrame=new JFrame("Input Verifier");
        jFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,1,5));
        JTextField jTextField1=new JTextField(10);
        JTextField jTextField2=new JTextField(10);
        jTextField1.setInputVerifier(new Verify());
        jTextField2.setInputVerifier(new Verify());
        jFrame.add(jTextField1);
        jFrame.add(jTextField2);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Verify extends InputVerifier
    {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input)
        {
            return !((JTextField) input).getText().equals("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't understand :-). could be awfull, not users_friendly, focus could be asynchronous, I'd be suggest to wrap inside invokeLater

Comment: Thx, I tried this, and it works but only on second focus (when launched, the focus is on the 1-st textfield, and I can still switch to the second and back without any input, only after this it works as intended and doesn't allow to lose focus of the field until I input smth).How to correct this?

Comment: @KatrinnaL Well that cannot be (did you properly copy the code) as in my test runs the focus could not be switched to the second even on the first turn.